# Is it possible to change the images source that are shown in the admin side?

Tags: wp-admin, cdn

All of my images are in a CDN. On the website that's where the images are coming from but on the admin side it is pulling them from the server.

Is there a filter or action I can use to change the source of the images that are shown in the WYSIWYG and in the Media admin section?

Comment: To my Knowledge, the Media Library isn't organizable, and I'd leave the Admin Pane alone, as the admin panel uses the php files native to your install.

Comment: I am looking at the media.php code to see if I can find a filter that could be useful.

Comment: The issue with that is: Each time there is a WordPress Update, ie. 3.9.2, you'll overwrite your "hack" with the update if you do find one

Comment: I actually worked out a solution. It is possible to do it without modifying WordPress code.